# Displaying the directory list

Tags: command, cygwin, sh, processbuilder, dir

Trying the following program in Eclipse.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
command.add("C:\\cygwin" + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh");
command.add("-c");
command.add("dir");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
final Process process = builder.start();
```

but the output is;
..Error..
/usr/bin/sh: dir: command not found

Can somebody tell me what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `C:\cygwin\bin\sh`, the Cygwin Bourne shell, from a non-Cygwin program.

That's fine, but the Cygwin process doesn't have the same `$PATH` it would have if you instead logged into Cygwin.  That's why `sh` can't find the `dir` command.

Try changing this:

```
command.add("dir");
```

to this:

```
command.add("/bin/dir");
```

Note that "/bin/dir" is the Cygwin-style path for the `dir` command, which is what `sh` recognizes.

An alternative would be to set `$PATH` in the `sh` process, for example by invoking it as:

```
 C:\cygwin\bin\sh -c "PATH=/usr/bin dir"
```

(I'll leave it to you to translate that into a form usable with Processbuilder.)